# Copy to another folder and add date stamp

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have been all over forums and cant seem to find what i need and as i am total newbe to a writing batch files I cant really modify the ones I have found.

I need a file that will copy all files with extension .dwg (or all files in the folder) to another folder with added date stamp at the beginning. the point is to keep only one set of files in the main directory and to make a copy in the archive folder.

Answer (score 4):

```
rem Get the current date
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic OS GET LocalDateTime') do if not defined LocalDateTime set LocalDateTime=%%x
set MyDate=%LocalDateTime:~0,8%

rem Create folder
set Folder=some\other\path\%MyDate%-archive
mkdir %Folder%

rem Copy files
copy *.dwg %Folder%
```

**EDIT:** If you just want the date added to the files, use the following instead:

```
for %%F in (*.dwg) do copy "%%F" "\some\other\path\%MyDate%_%%F"
```

Comment: great! this works , bu it creates new folder. is it possible to just add date stamp on the copied file. So I would have k:\work\file.dwg copied and renamed into k:work\archive\2012-06-29_file.dwg

Answer (score 0):

Try something like these:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
MYFOLDER=/archive

for DWGFILE in $( ls *.dwg )
do
   cp $DWGFILE $MYFOLDER/$TIMESTAMP-$DWGFILE
done
```

Comment: Should I copy this to notepad and make .bat file? and where is the name of the archive folder?
BTW.thanks for the answer

Comment: No. I'm sorry, this is a bash script for linux, not bat. :-)